# How can I get system time from a proc file?

Tags: linux, procfs

How can I get system time from a proc file? I know we can get system time from some commands such as date, and also can write some code based on time API. But I really need to use a simple proc file to get the time. No matter what the time format is, a simple value is OK. For example, the total seconds from 1970/1/1 is really good enough.

Comment: First you need to modify the proc filesystem to include this information.

Comment: Care to explain *why* you need it specifically from proc file? Maybe there is some other way that would serve the ultimate goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the amount of time since the system booted from `/proc/uptime`, but there is no way I know of to get the real time from `/proc`.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, you can :

```
cat /proc/driver/rtc
```

From man:

```
RTC vs system clock
   RTCs should not be confused with the system clock, which is a
   software clock maintained by the kernel and used to implement
   gettimeofday(2) and time(2), as well as setting timestamps on files,
   and so on.  The system clock reports seconds and microseconds since a
   start point, defined to be the POSIX Epoch: 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000
   (UTC).
```

More [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/rtc.4.html)

Comment: Does /proc/driver/rtc always show the time in UTC? It does on my laptop (Ubuntu 14.04) although my system time (as shown by /bin/date) is in BST (UTC+1)